# What is the origin of "cool beans"?

Tags: etymology, slang

**What is the origin of "cool beans"?** I know some sites (wiktionary) claim it's from the Cheech & Chong 1978 movie *Up in Smoke*, but I'm talking to people who remember it being used earlier.  (USA).

I remember using the phrase in  the mid-1980s (elementary school in Maryland) , and I assumed it had to do with Jelly Belly (a gourmet jelly bean company).

Comment: I don't know why the idea that it originated with Cheech & Chong persists, but the word "beans" does not actually appear in any of the transcripts. caption files, or screenplays I have found online.

Comment: I've read it a few times and assumed it was some sort of Beatnik expression.  "Cool", of course, is a well-known Beatnik term, but what is meant by "beans" in this context is unclear (Urban Dictionary gives several likely meanings).

Comment: The captured German in the film “Saving Private Ryan” says “cool beans” when trying to convince the American soldiers how much he loves America. So if that’s anything to go by then its been around since at least 1944.

Comment: Well, *oeuf corse* is better in this sense. [say it out loud, folks, think French).

Answer (score 4):

The Oxford English Dictionary's earliest attestation for "cool beans" is from the 1985 book [Grandpa Ritz and the Luscious Lovelies](https://books.google.com/books?id=lIXDYh-yqeMC&q="Oh,+wow!+Cool+beans!%E2%80%99+I+whispered."):

> "Oh, wow! Cool beans!" I whispered.

Comment: Elsewhere in the same book (page 30): "'It's cool beans!' That's what Betsy always says when she thinks something is fantastic, and I couldn't help wondering what she'd say if she could see me now. ..." J.E. Lighter, _Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang_ (1994) notes that in the early 20th century "beans!" by itself was "used to indicate surprise, annoyance, disbelief, etc."; Lighter cites an example from O. Johnson, _Stover at Yale_ (1911): "Oh, beans!" This may be an unrelated usage, however.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find where I read this, but I recollect from my college days as a linguistics minor, that it originated from the French-Canadian explorers “cours bien” meaning “the course/path is good.” I can dig it.

Comment: Tommie, this might be a very good answer if it can be backed up by authoritative sources. I think you might rewrite the answer with some sources, and not have us depend on recollection.

Comment: I have been trying to find the source!  Thus far, I have found nothing and I know I didn' t make it up! I'm not that smart!  It makes me feel like I am crazy...It has become my mission to find the source.  I even dug out some of my linguistics texts. I will find it! :)

Comment: I like this -- if you can find a citation, that will be my official explanation in the future!

Comment: Good for you, Tommie1

Comment: OK.  I give up.  I cannot find any "true" etymology of this phrase, only reference.  I even went into researchgate/google scholar and read a few theses of interest.  Also, I learned a lot about the Voyageurs of Canada (very interesting, BTW). Perhaps I read this on Wikipedia eons ago and it was since overtaken by some other "expert" and whatever I read about "cours bien" was complete BS?  I've used this phrase off and on since at least the early 80s.  I did find this which was interesting, but again, no real source:  http://www.word-detective.com/2009/11/cool-beans

Comment: Also, I tried looking in WorldCat and other research databases through my university library, but I've already wasted too much time on this. If I ever go back to school for linguistics, perhaps this will be my thesis/dissertation.  And for what? It'll all just amount to a hill of beans.

Comment: I found what I remembered reading regarding "cours bien" for "cool beans". See the link:
https://www.seslisozluk.net/en/what-is-the-meaning-of-cool-beans

Comment: Link only answers are generally considered low quality as they become useless if the linked page is changed or removed.

Comment: @TommieChristine It looks like you've signed into the wrong account and posted a new answer when you meant to edit your previous one? Adding the link as a reference would make a great addition to your other answer, but shouldn't be posted separately here.

Comment: The paragraph in your link originated on [Wiktionary in 2011](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:MobileDiff/11613556), added by an anonymous user. I'd expect that this is the only evidence you'll find in favor of this alleged etymology, because they surely made the entire thing up, even the alleged original French.

Answer (score 2):

The term shows up in a couple of college newspapers in 1984 and 1985. The 1984 one is from a page full of end-of-the school-year personals in The Daily Northwestern at Northwestern University. It reads, in part:

> "It's been a great year my friend! Here's to your cool-beans smile and great laugh!" - "The Last Personal". *The Daily Northwestern*, May 24, 1984, p8